# Sails.js 1.0 helpers chaining as Promises

Tags: sails.js

I'm new to Sails.js and I'm looking to develop a new application using sail.js and in this application, I want to respond to a POST request as quickly as possible, then handle a number of tasks with the payload asynchronously. Ideally I'd have a helper for each step of the tasks I want to carry out on the payload and chain them all asynchronously in the action. I've been trawling through the docs and can't seem to find a way to do this.

Is this the right way to approach this issue (if so how/can you point me to docs) or are there alternative ways to handle this issue that I have overlooked?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you can use [helpers](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers/example-helper) both with async/await or as promises.

```
const temp1 = await sails.helpers.stepone();
const temp2 = await sails.helpers.steptwo( temp1 );
let result  = await sails.helpers.stepthree( temp2 );
// use result here
```

OR

```
sails.helpers.stepone
.then(sails.helpers.steptwo)
.then(sails.helpers.stepthree)
.then(result => {
  // use result here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set up your service methods as promises and resolve early.  You can import `bluebird`, for example, to accomplish this.
In your controller:

```
myPostEndpoint: (req, res) => {
  return MyProcessorService.initProcessing(req.body).then(res.json);
}
```

And in your service `MyProcessorService`:

```
var Promise = import('bluebird');
//... other init code

module.exports = {
  initProcessing: data => {
    //do some validation...
    // then just resolve and continue
    Promise.resolve({ status: 'processing'});

    return MyProcessorService.step1(data)
      .then(MyProcessorService.step2)
      .then(MyProcessorService.step3)//and so on....
  },
  step1: dataFromInit => { 
    //do stuff and resolve for step2  
  },
  step2: dataFromStep1 => { 
    //do stuff and resolve for step3  
  },
  step3: dataFromStep2 => { 
    //do stuff and resolve 
  },
  //and so on
}
```

You could also set up a worker queue with something like [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) and [Redis](https://redis.io/) to send off jobs to and run in a WorkerService or separate worker app.

Comment: I think @rrforshort was asking specifically about helpers, rather than the older services structure.  https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers

Comment: @carpiediem  Helpers are already asynchronous.  I assumed the OP meant "helpers" in a generic sense at the time, but you could be right.